# Problem to research a special character in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file (I only show a part) where I would like to remove a special character.

```
OTU1359 UniRef90_A0A095VQ09 UniRef90_A0A0C1UI80 UniRef90_A0A1M4ZSK2 UniRef90_A0A1W1CJV7 UniRef90_A0A1Z9J2X0 UniRef90_A0A1Z9THL2 UniRef90_A0A2E3B6A5 UniRef90_A0A2E5MT47 UniRef90_A0A2E5VCW9 UniRef90_A0A2E6CDK4 UniRef90_A0A2E6KTE6 UniRef90_A0A2E8AIM6 UniRef90_A0A2E8RIG1 UniRef90_A0A2E8YNS3 UniRef90_A0A2E9VEK0 UniRef90_W6RCT6

OTU0980 UniRef90_A0A084TMQ7 UniRef90_A0A090PK65 UniRef90_A0A0P1G8P0 UniRef90_A0A0P1IHL1 UniRef90_A0A286ILS7 UniRef90_A0A2A5E7H9 UniRef90_A0A2D9J217 UniRef90_H3NS47 UniRef90_H3NSN9 UniRef90_H3NSP0 UniRef90_H3NSP7 UniRef90_H3NUB2 UniRef90_H3NY28 UniRef90_H3NY47 UniRef90_UPI000C2CBC51
```

I would like to remove the character "OTUXXXX" (it always start by OTU and has always 4 numbers after) . It can appears multiple OTUXXXX by line

I tried :

`re.search("OTU[0-9]{4}", line)`

It doesn't work.. Any help?

Comment: `re.sub(r"\s*\bOTU[0-9]{4}\b", "", line).strip()`?

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I wanted, thanks.

Comment: as posted above, you need to use re.sub to substitute. also the ```r``` part tells python that the string is literal, avoiding problems with ```\``` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `re.sub` and find your pattern matches as whole words to avoid partial matches inside other words.

```
s = re.sub(r"\s*\bOTU[0-9]{4}\b", "", line).strip()
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TcvIRO/1). The `.strip()` at the end removes any redundant leading/trailing whitespaces that remain after removing the matches at the end/start of the string.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cs*%5CbOTU%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%5Cb):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `re.sub` which actually performs replacemnt or substitution of matching text with the one you provide. Here you find the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

And here one possible implementaiton:

```
from re import compile, sub, MULTILINE

text = '''
OTU1359 UniRef90_A0A095VQ09 UniRef90_A0A0C1UI80 UniRef90_A0A1M4ZSK2 UniRef90_A0A1W1CJV7 UniRef90_A0A1Z9J2X0 UniRef90_A0A1Z9THL2 UniRef90_A0A2E3B6A5 UniRef90_A0A2E5MT47 UniRef90_A0A2E5VCW9 UniRef90_A0A2E6CDK4 UniRef90_A0A2E6KTE6 UniRef90_A0A2E8AIM6 UniRef90_A0A2E8RIG1 UniRef90_A0A2E8YNS3 UniRef90_A0A2E9VEK0 UniRef90_W6RCT6

OTU0980 UniRef90_A0A084TMQ7 UniRef90_A0A090PK65 UniRef90_A0A0P1G8P0 UniRef90_A0A0P1IHL1 UniRef90_A0A286ILS7 UniRef90_A0A2A5E7H9 UniRef90_A0A2D9J217 UniRef90_H3NS47 UniRef90_H3NSN9 UniRef90_H3NSP0 UniRef90_H3NSP7 UniRef90_H3NUB2 UniRef90_H3NY28 UniRef90_H3NY47 UniRef90_UPI000C2CBC51
'''

replacemnt = ''
regex = compile(r'OTU\d{4}', flags=MULTILINE)
cleaned = sub(regex, replacemnt, text)
```

Comment: Why do you use `flags=MULTILINE`? You have no `^` and `$` in the pattern to modify the behavior of.

Comment: In the example text there are multiple lines! I didn't make assumptions on how the regex will be used/edited. It's there just for compliance with given data.

Comment: Regex matches are searched for in all the text, on all lines, by default. `re.MULTILINE` has nothing to do with the text, it only affects what `^` and `$` match in the pattern.